# css overflow-x (or y): hidden breaks javascript .scrollTop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use a javascript to change a div when you past a certain height scrolling:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scroll > 300){
            $('#div').addClass('class');
        }
        if(scroll > 500){
            $('#div').removeClass('class');
        }

    });
```

But on the CSS, the properties:

```
body, html{
    overflow-y: overlay
    overflow-x: hidden
}
```

makes the Javascript useless, and it's both X and Y, i've tried with only one hidden, unset, etc.
And they need to be BOTH unset for this script to work.

I would like any way to go around this, either a new Javascript function or any other way to hide the scroll bars. Thank you :)

Tried: CSS overflow:hidden + Javascript scrollTop
Expected: work
Result: didn't work

Comment: `overlay` is invalid value for `overflow-y` properties

Comment: My WebStorm html editor says the same, but it actually changes the bar when I use it. Anyways, that's not the point of the post, since changing it to hidden wouldn't make the java script work :<

Comment: it seems a task suited for [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)